# Sound HTML with Java Script?

Tags: javascript, audio, playback

I am making a small project with HTML and I would like to play MP3 files in the background one sound all the time in a loop. How do I do that I am new to Java Script.

Comment: [There's really just one - **one** - site on the net that gets to auto-play music without incurring universal hatred.](http://zombo.com)

Comment: I'm trying to find a duplicate … but I can't find any questions that have done as little research as this to be a good duplicate.

Comment: I have done some research but the problem is that Garry's Mod only allows JavaScript.

Comment: What does Garry's Mod have to do with this question!?

Comment: This is a bad idea and extremely uncommon and unwanted by almost *all* users **.** <- "period" Do everyone a favor; don't do it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use Javascript to do this, you can just add the following to your html markup:

```
<audio autoplay loop>
<source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
<source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
<p>Your browser does not support the audio element </p>
</audio>
```

Just make sure to add a couple of source elements in there to support multiple browser. You can leave out the p-tag if you want it to not do anything on non-supporting browsers, and you can take off the controls if you want to hide the controls.

I do have to say, this is not recommended and I think it doesn't work on iOS (as it won't actually load in the audio before the user interacts with the page - although that might have been a Javascript limitation).

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FHTML%2FUsing_HTML5_audio_and_video

I do have to agree though, it's not a good idea. People hated it in the nineties, people hate it today. Nobody wants unexpected sounds coming out of their speaker system.